# Open windows maximized!

Tags: ccsm

I want some of the application to be opened in a maximized state. Can I have windows open in a maximised state? Does CCSM provide a way to do that?

Answer (score 4):

This can be done with CCSM's *Window rules*.

**CompizConfig Settings Manager (CCSM)** is available in *Universe* section of repository, so allow the repo. and install it using:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) universe"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

### The Steps:

1. Start CCSM, and go to <kbd>Window Management</kbd>. Check mark <kbd>Window Rules</kbd> and click;
   [image: snap1]
2. Under the <kbd>Matches</kbd> tab, click the <kbd>**+**</kbd> button next to the Maximized field so that *Edit Match* window appears;
   [image: snap2]
3. In the *Edit Match* window, select the *Type* you want and use <kbd>**Or**</kbd> for the *Relation*. Next open the the target application which you want to start maximized each time it is called (in the example snapshot below I'm using *Chromium* browser as the new target; I've already added *Software Centre* to the rule). Then click the <kbd>Grab</kbd> button in *Edit Match* window so that a *reticle or crosshair* appears; move it over and click on the target application's window. The proper value should then appear in the *Value* field, and click <kbd>Add</kbd>;
   [image: snap3]
4. That's it, you can add more applications to the rule or reset by clicking the reset button next to <kbd>**+**</kbd> icon.
   [image: snap4]

Similarly you can set the rules for *Fullscreen*, *Non Movable windows*, etc.

---

You can also specify custom sizes for application window under <kbd>Window Management</kbd> -> <kbd>Window Rules</kbd> -> <kbd>Size Rules</kbd>.

[image: snap5]