# Nautilus opened minimized

Tags: 13.04, nautilus

When I open the directory of a file, Nautilus is opened minimized. 
How can I make open in maximized as main window ?

Comment: Nasreddine the [answer here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/428850/open-windows-maximized) should help you with `nautilus` too..

Comment: @rusty thanks. Solved by installing compiz plugins (sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins)

Comment: nice to know it's fixed..

Answer (score 1):

If you maximize nautilus and then close it, the next time you open it, it will be maximized.  I think that is what you are asking.  Otherwise, please elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish.