# Force all windows to open maximized

Tags: ccsm, maximized

I'm on Ubuntu 22.04.3 -- The recommended post "Open windows maximized!" is many years old. I've followed the instructions carefully and restarted and no windows in the apps identified are opening maximized. Is there a more updated solution to this?

(Original post was at [Open windows maximized!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/428850/open-windows-maximized/428852#428852?newreg=7500f7f4623e4bba84d3de0e3010c1ab))

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are probably unable to follow the original solution might be because back then the Desktop Environment was different.

Assuming you are using GNOME, you could try this extension: [One Window Wonderland](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5696/one-window-wonderland/).

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to figure out how to get that working, stuck on this error from the GSE: "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector."

I'll keep digging into that documentation, but if you have a quick solution I'd so appreciate any insights. Thx again much appreciated.